# Simple Mode - Is using checkpoints to truncate the transaction log a bad practice?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with simple recovery mode. For that database I have a job running every morning. This job imports data and executes plenty stored procedures that inserts data, updates records, delete records, makes calculations... The job takes approximately 30 minutes and makes the transaction log be 10GB big. To avoid growth of the log file during the job I set the log size to 11GB. With that amount it is never autogrowing. Nevertheless it is blocking 11GB. I think it is useless knowing that I will never need to make a recovery (every job empties all the tables and populate them from scratch every morning).

I just read that putting checkpoints truncates the log. So my idea is to put checkpoints at several location in my stored procedures in order to be able to minimize the size of the log (from 11GB to lot less: 3GB for instance).

Question: is it dangerous to do that take into consideration once again that I will never have to make recoveries?